# cannot return arraylist from web service

Tags: java, web-services

here is my code for web service

```
    package com.notification;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotificationMessage {
 public List<String> message(){
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  al.add("Meeting at 12");
  al.add("School at 10am on 6");
  al.add("Holiday on 8th");
  return al;
 }
}
```

I want to return an arraylist containing String objects

but it gives following error

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String Message: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: what webservice framework or mechanism you are using

Comment: Am testing this code using eclipse. I havent written any client code for now as my service itself is not returning object

Comment: probably your wsdl contains the operation which has return type of String

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine. The error stack trace you're showing has nothing to do with this. Can you give us a bit more information?

Comment: Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file. Message: ; nested exception is: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I tried lot and finally succeed. As per my knowledge you can not return direct arraylist in web service,because ArrayList is a concept of Java only.
You need to create a separate POJO class for the arraylist

POJO Class :-

```
public class ResponseDataArrayList {
    ArrayList list;
    public ArrayList getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }   
}
```

Now you need a small changes in Implementation method.Just set your arraylist using setter method.Also change the return type of the method to POJO class type.These steps are most important.

```
public ResponseDataArrayList getProdList(){

        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();           
        al.add("Meeting at 12");
       al.add("School at 10am on 6");
       al.add("Holiday on 8th");

        ResponseDataArrayList objwrapper=new ResponseDataArrayList();
        objwrapper.setList(al);

        return objwrapper;
    }
```

Now change the WSDL file accordingly .If you are running the application using Eclipse then just right click on project -> Run on Server.

Hope is will help you.